# Error: Unable to resolve module react-native/Libraries/Animated/src/Easing

Tags: react-native

i am a new learner about react-native,today i planned to use teaset ,i read the docs,followin instructions:

```
npm install --save teaset
```

i installed teaset,then i used a example from docs,code as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

import { View, AppRegistry } from 'react-native';

import { Label } from 'teaset';

class HelloWorldApp extends Component {
render() {
return (
<View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>


);
}
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('HelloWorldApp', () => HelloWorldApp);
There was an error when I was running on my Android phone:
: Error: Unable to resolve module react-native/Libraries/Animated/src/Easing from E:\test\test1\node_modules\teaset\components\ListRow\TouchableOpacity.js: react-native/Libraries/Animated/src/Easing could not be found within the project or in these directories:
node_modules

If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:

1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
2. Delete node_modules and run yarn install
3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
   so,what should i do to solve the prlblem,i will be crazy.

Comment: Are you sure you installed the module in the correct folder?

Comment: I use the command directly in the terminal of vscode that is 'yarn add teaset'

Comment: This command is directly used in the root directory of the project. I have encountered this problem many times. I don't know how to solve it. If you can help me, I will be very grateful

Comment: There's a new issue in the teaset whick is the exact one you told,here's the link.
https://github.com/rilyu/teaset/issues/444

Comment: thank you for your help，i am very happy